# Python-ML:confusion_matrix from sklrearn

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I know what confusion matrix is and how to use it. From [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix) and some other examples I understand how binary confusion is set up(C(0,0)= "upper left place in matrix"  = predicted:false, actual false =false nefgatives). I alsu assume "actual" is always on y axis and "predicted" on x axis. But what is
 C(0,0) in multinomial case, when I have for examle 4x4 matrix?
I notices it goes by alphabetical order from left to right on x axise and toward bottom in y axis, if first letter are the same second letter decides by alphabetical order, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, based on the [github repository](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L182), unless you specify otherwise, the order is sorted (thus in particular alphabetical).

Specifically, according to the link above:

> labels : array, shape = [n_classes], optional 
>            List of labels to index the matrix. This may be used to reorder 
>            or select a subset of labels. 
>            If none is given, those that appear at least once 
>            in `y_true` or `y_pred` are used in sorted order.

where `labels` is one of the inputs to the confusion matrix function:

```
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=None, sample_weight=None)
```